# How do you uninstall openbox/gnome?

Tags: 12.04, unity, lxde, openbox

So I installed a couple desktop environments like gnome and lxde for my older computer because unity seemed really slow afterwards I logged out and went to select one and notice after I installed lxde it installed openbox and openbox/gnome. Openbox is fine but openbox/gnome doesn't work at all when I start it seems to just load the desktop blank and the right and left click are not showing the openbox like options so clearly it isn't working. How would I uninstall openbox/gnome but keep just openbox and why did lxde install it in the first place?

Comment: What is "openbox/gnome"? There, apparently, is no such package, and LXDE doesn't install something like that. Can you add an explanation to the question.

Comment: Actually yes it does, Installing LXDE somehow creates a session called openbox-gnome and it doesn't work. Search for the Session file in /usr/share/xsessions and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

In a ternimal, navigate to `/usr/share/xsessions`:

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
```

this will contain `.desktop` files for the desktop environments.
simply delete the entries for `gnome-openbox` (and openbox if desired).

It sounds like openbox is required by LXDE, so uninstalling is probably risky. Removing the desktop option is safer.